# ASP.NET MVC, File Upload on Multiple Controller/Server Calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am working with ASP.NET MVC3 and the Kendo UI File Upload Control.

The logic of my screen goes like this:

1. User uploads a file and information gets extracted from the file and gets displayed back to the user.  This is a call to the controller from the view.  The file does not get saved to disk at this point.  It is only analyzed by the controller with results sent back to view.
2. Based upon what the user sees in the file, he/she will manipulate other things on the screen.
3. Once finished user will click the submit button, making another call to the server/controller.  If the validation of the information the user entered passed validation, then I actually want to save the uploaded file to disk.

So is there any way that my second call to the controller can have access to the file from the first call to the controller?  The second call to the controller is where I need to save it to disk and give it a file name.  Or do I need to send the file from the view to the controller twice?

Comment: you can use all the information posted on second call to create the file, then why do you need original file again?

Comment: The original upload extracts data from the file and displays it to the user without actually saving the file to the server disk.

Comment: My validation does not happen until after the file upload was processed.  If validation fails, I do not want to actually save the file to the server disk.

Comment: yes, that is what even my point is. You got original file information,  which you display it to user. He updates the information, then posts that information back to you (server). You validate that information and create that file on server.

Comment: No I am not sending the info from the file back to the server.  The user is making other decisions based on this info.  I guess what I'm saying is I don't want to save the file to disk until the 2nd controller/server call

Comment: I'm assuming I can do this by sending the file in the HttpPostedFileBase array on both the 1st and 2nd calls to the server/controller.  I am trying to avoid sending it twice and only send it on the first call.